# Datatables rows.add() with an object array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to clear out my existing Datatable and redraw it with new data from an Ajax function. I have looked at other questions with solutions to draw the data but for some reason it is not working.

I am using this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('exams/ajax_list'); ?>/"+site,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(data); // Add new data
        table.draw(); // Redraw the DataTable
    }
});
```

When I `console.log(data)` I get an object array of 7 items. So I'm wondering why the table is not updating? I just get a message in the Datatable that says "No data available in table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this:

```
 table.rows.add(data.data); // Add new data
```

In my PHP file I did `echo json_encode(['data'] => $data]);`

So adding the `.data` let me access the array.

**console.log(data):** gave me the object array
**console.log(data.data):** gave me the plain array

Thanks